# Como utilizar a string criada string.xml via código

Tags: java, android

Como utilizar a `string` criada `strings.xml` via código
exemplo tem como chamar `<string name="hello_world">Hello world!</string>` em algum momento no código (**Activity**).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recomendo uma leitura deste tópico:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html

Mas para referenciar a uma String localizada nos resources/values, é deste modo:

```
String string = getString(R.string.hello);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String mensagem = getResources().getString(R.string.hello_world);
```

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html